# Cannot read Application Properties from EventHub

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, net-library

I managed to get connection with Azure IoTHub to send and receive device2Cloud Messages. I send the message with Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client DeviceClient & consume the messages with Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;

This is my code for sending the telemetry data

```
public async Task<IoTClientStatistics> SendDeviceToCloudMessageAsync(string messageContents)
        {
            if (_deviceClient == null || IsInitialized == false)
                throw new InvalidAsynchronousStateException("You must call Initialize() before sending a message");

            // IoT Hub message is a specific object that takes a byte array. 
            // You can then do many things...
            Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageContents));

            // ...For example: add a custom application property to the message.
            // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
            // Here we add the current runtime platform (Android, iOS, ...)
            //message.Properties.Add("platform", Device.RuntimePlatform);
            message.Properties.Add("name", "DeviceSample");
          

            try
            {
                // Sending the event. If the event fails to be sent (no network, etc...)
                // an exception will be raised.
                await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent!");
                // Updating statistics
                _statistics.MessagesSent += 1;
                _statistics.LastMessageSent = messageContents;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _statistics.LastMessageSent = "Error: " + e;
                _statistics.SendFailures += 1;
            }

            return _statistics;
        }
```

This is my code for receiving the telemetry data

```
public async void ReceiveDeviceToCloudMessageAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                using CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cancellationSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));

                int eventsRead = 0;
                int maximumEvents = 2;

                var readEvents = _eventHubConsumerClient.ReadEventsAsync(cancellationSource.Token);
               
                await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in readEvents)
                {

                    string readFromPartition = partitionEvent.Partition.PartitionId;
                    byte[] eventBodyBytes = partitionEvent.Data.EventBody.ToArray();

                    yellowMessage($"\nMessage received on partition {partitionEvent.Partition.PartitionId}:");

                    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(partitionEvent.Data.Body.ToArray());

                    greenMessage($"\tMessage body: {data}");

                    _statistics.MessagesReceived++;
                    _statistics.LastMessageReceived = data;

                    yellowMessage("\tApplication properties (set by device):");
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> prop in partitionEvent.Data.Properties)
                    {
                        PrintProperties(prop);

                    }

                    yellowMessage("\tSystem properties (set by IoT Hub):");
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> prop in partitionEvent.Data.SystemProperties)
                    {
                        PrintProperties(prop);
                    }

                    eventsRead++;

                    if (eventsRead >= maximumEvents)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException e)
            {
                redMessage(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Problem is all the application properties I received at the partitionEvent DO NOT contain the application properties I added for the sent messages.
There is 1 possibility which still do not make sense to me, first my IoT device is configured to ignore message Application Properties. But I tested on another client app and the application properties were there normally (Using a Console App to send & a console app to receive with the same Key configuration)

Still struggle to understand why this is happening,
Is there any one expert on this topic ?

Comment: Hey guys, I figured out the reason why this is. My other application did not use the parameter CancellationToken for ReadEventAsync while my application uses. I guess this is the difference in timing that causes not able to read the Application Properties. In a way, this is a convenient thing for me.

Comment: Respectfully, your conclusion is not correct.  The use of a cancellation token is orthogonal.  In your example, the cancellation token serves as a safety to break out of your loop if you haven't received 2 events within 45 seconds.  An event is read in its entirety from the Event Hubs service; the AMQP message is not translated into an `EventData` instance until the entire message is confirmed.    Anything present in the `ApplicationProperties` section of the AMQP message is written to the `EventData.Properties` collection.  If your event didn't have properties, Event Hubs didn't receive them.

Comment: Is it possible that you've got events present in the Event Hub that were published without properties associated with them?   Calling `ReadEvents` will read from the beginning of each partition of the Event Hub by default.   What your publisher just sent won't be seen until you read all events that had been previously published.    Since you're reading only 2 events each execution,  I wonder if you're only seeing old data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, your points are right regarding the Cancellation token is not the problem here, I set a maximum read of 2, that's why it read the event 2 times and break the reading. Is it possible that if I set it to higher number (i.e. 8), it can read all the events. Remember also that there is some configuration on the device (the IoT device not directly managed by me), and the also the transport protocol I'm using for sending is MQTT, not AMQP

Comment: I don't think it was old data and not sure what exactly you meant by that. Do you think the messages are stored? Should I read from Last Message using readEventAsync?

Comment: Because events are never removed from the event stream in Event Hubs, you will continue reading the same events over and over, never getting more than 2 deep on any partition and never seeing any new events that you publish.   Using `ReadEvents`,  each time you execute your code, it is reading from every partition, starting with the first event in each with no guarantees on which partitions you'll see first.

Comment: _and the also the transport protocol I'm using for sending is MQTT, not AMQP_  Event Hubs is AMQP-based.   IoT Hub is translating your MQTT data behind the scenes.   I can't speak to the IoT Hub portions with any great detail, however.